# a little doubt while solving questions on resolving a vector into components components

Tags: vectors, physics

**Question** Find the components of a force P along two directions making angles 45 and 30° with it
on opposite sides.

---

I have no idea about its figure.

[image]

I solved using this but got wrong answer.

Comment: How did you solve it? We might be able to point out where your error is.

Comment: https://imgur.com/6mBMynx this is my solution, since we are asked to find components of P along given directions.

Comment: Your approach would only work if $F_1$ and $F_2$ are perpendicular to each other. Otherwise, you need to decompose $P$ as done in the answer

Answer (score 2):

[image]

The problem is about vector decomposition, where $\vec{P}$ is decomposed into $\vec{F_1}$ and $\vec{F_2}$,

$$\vec{P} = \vec{F_1}+ \vec{F_2}$$

Geometrically, they form a parallelogram as shown in the diagram. Use the cosine rule to establish,

$$F_2^2=P^2+F_1^2-2PF_1\cos45°$$
$$F_1^2=P^2+F_2^2-2PF_2\cos30°$$

The solution to this set of equations are,

$$F_1 = \frac{\sqrt{2}P}{1+\sqrt{3}}=\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2})P$$
$$F_2 = \frac{2P}{1+\sqrt{3}}=(\sqrt{3}-1)P$$

Alternatively, one could also set up the equations using the sine rule as well,

$$\frac{F_2}{F_1} = \frac{\sin45°}{\sin 30°}$$
$$ F_1\cos 45° + F_2\cos 30° = P$$

which is easier to solve since they are linear and gives the same results.

Answer (score 1):

**Problems with Dot Product Approach**

In the asker's work they present their solution as taking the dot product to find the components. This approach is logical if you are trying to only see the projection of $\vec{P}$ along $\hat{F_1}$ and $\hat{F_2}$ independently or if $\hat{F_1}$ and $\hat{F_2}$ were perpendicular. For this problem this is not the case and if the question is one of decomposition the dot product approach leads to an issue where components of $\vec{P}$ are double counted.

$$
(\vec{P}\cdot\hat{F_1})\hat{F_1}+(\vec{P}\cdot\hat{F_2})\hat{F_2} = |P|\left<\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4},\frac{1}{2}+\frac{3}{4},0\right>\neq\vec{P}=|P|\left<0,1,0\right>$$

---

**A Possible Approach**

Let's start small and see if we can work it out shall we:

What we know:
$$\begin{array}{rccc}\vec{P}=\langle & 0,&P,&0\rangle\\\vec{F_1}=\langle & \sin(45^\circ)F_1,&\cos(45^\circ)F_1,&0\rangle\\\vec{F_2}=\langle & -\sin(30^\circ)F_2,&\cos(30^\circ)F_2,&0\rangle\end{array}$$

What we want to know:
$F_1, F_2$

Do you think you can setup equations and solve this?

Sounds like we need another hint: Look component wise:
In the $x$ direction we have that
$$\sin(45^\circ)F1 - \sin(30^\circ)F2= 0$$
In the $y$ direction we have:
$$\cos(45^\circ)F1 + \cos(30^\circ)F2 = P$$
We thus have two linear equations and two unknowns. Can you solve it from here?

Comment: You will have a better time in trying to typeset things aligned in a certain way using arrays.  `$\begin{array}{rccc}\vec{P}=\langle & 0,&P,&0\rangle\\\vec{F}=\langle & \sin(45^\circ)F_1,&\cos(45^\circ)F_1,&0\rangle\end{array}$` for instance yields $\begin{array}{rccc}\vec{P}=\langle & 0,&P,&0\rangle\\\vec{F}=\langle & \sin(45^\circ)F_1,&\cos(45^\circ)F_1,&0\rangle\end{array}$.  The `{rccc}` is a list of alignments, in this case right, center, center, center.  You can use bars as well to indicate if you want horizontal lines to separate columns.

Comment: Read more about typesetting arrays [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/5044#5044).

Comment: @Quanto and kitter  I think you didn't read the question well, it is asking components of **P** along two given directions

Comment: @lucifer I think F1 is the component along the F1 direction and F2 is the component along the F2 direction.

Comment: Fine, please solve further :)